# Image sliding while using a slice effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to make a slideshow with some great effects. Im trying to make the image slide while making a slice function. The slice function of the image slideshow works fine, but i can't seem to figure out how to make the image change while im using my slice function.

HTML:

```
<div class="sliced">
   <img id='img1' src="../Images/germany.png" />
   <img id='img2' src="../Images/test.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sliced {
position: relative;
width: 640px; 
height: 400px;
}
.sliced img {
position: absolute;
width: 640px; 
height: 400px;
}
.tile { 
float: left;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.tile-animated {
    opacity: 0;
}
.css3-preload .sliced * {
-webkit-transition: none !important;
-moz-transition: none !important;
-ms-transition: none !important;
-o-transition: none !important;
transition: none !important;
}
```

AND JAVASRIPT:

```
;(function( $, window ) {
var _defaults = {
x      : 2, // number of tiles in x axis
y      : 2, // number of tiles in y axis
random : true, // animate tiles in random order
speed  : 2000 // time to clear all times
  };
* range Get an array of numbers within a range
* @param min {number} Lowest number in array
 * @param max {number} Highest number in array
 * @param rand {bool} Shuffle array
* @return {array}
  */



function range( min, max, rand ) {
var arr = ( new Array( ++max - min ) )
  .join('.').split('.')
  .map(function( v,i ){ return min + i})
return rand
  ? arr.map(function( v ) { return [ Math.random(), v ] })
     .sort().map(function( v ) { return v[ 1 ] })
  : arr
  }
// Prevent css3 transitions on load
$('body').addClass('css3-preload')
$( window ).load(function(){ $('body').removeClass('css3-preload') })
  $.fn.sliced = function( options ) {

var o = $.extend( {}, _defaults, options );

return this.each(function() {

  var $container = $(this);
  /*---------------------------------
   * Make the tiles:
   ---------------------------------*/

  var width = $container.width(),
      height = $container.height(),
      $img = $container.find('img'),
      n_tiles = o.x * o.y,
      tiles = [], $tiles;

  for ( var i = 0; i < n_tiles; i++ ) {
    tiles.push('<div class="tile" id="tile'+i+'"/>');
  }
  $tiles = $( tiles.join('') );

  // Hide original image and insert tiles in DOM
  $img.hide().after( $tiles );

  // Set background

  $tiles.css({
    width: width / o.x,
    height: height / o.y,
    backgroundImage: 'url('+ $img.attr('src') +')'
  });

  // Adjust position
  $tiles.each(function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $(this).css( 'backgroundPosition', -pos.left +'px '+ -pos.top +'px' );
  });

  /*---------------------------------
   * Animate the tiles:
   ---------------------------------*/

  var tilesArr = range( 0, n_tiles, o.random ),
      tileSpeed = o.speed / n_tiles; // time to clear a single tile

  // Public method
  $container.on( 'animate', function() {

    tilesArr.forEach(function( tile, i ) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        $tiles.eq( tile ).toggleClass( 'tile-animated' );
      }, i * tileSpeed );
    });

  });

});

  };

}( jQuery, window ));
$('.sliced').sliced({ x: 20, y: 15, speed: 1000 });


var timeCounter = 0;
var timeOut = window.setInterval(function(){
        if(timeCounter==0){
            $('.sliced').trigger('animate');
            timeCounter = 1100;
        } 
        if(timeCounter==1100) {
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('.sliced').trigger('animate');
            }, timeCounter);
            timeCounter = 0;
        }
}, 5000);
```

Note that this image slide-slice effect is found on http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/4nsJE/ .
I have changed the code a bit, so it loops every 5 second.

What gives me my problem is, that the Tiles seem to use the background of the image when loaded, and then the real image is hidden. I cannot find a way to change the background of the tiles, so that they will use the background of the other image.
//Please look at the jsfiddle to see how it works with a "click-button" to understand it more.

If you've got an answar on how i can solve my problem please feel free to tell me, and give me the code. However i would appreciate if you'd give a reasoning of why it works with your code.
It's important for the scripter that the code works, but more importantly is to know why it works.! :-)

Comment: Note that all JS code runs in a jquery $(document).ready()...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. Care to clarify?

Comment: If you have checked out the link i wrote, you'd see how the "slice-function" works. What i want to, is to slide image, like all slideshows do, while the "slice-func" is running.
Example: 
1: Displays IMG1
2: Runs slice function while IMG1 is displayed
3: while IMG1 is completely hidden, a new image(IMG2) should appear behind .TILES
4: The tiles is clearing, and IMG1 is now replaced by IMG2

And when the function runs 5000 miliseconds later, the same thing will happend the opposite way (IMG1 replaces IMG2)

Hope it makes some sense at least :-D